# 8 bit Analog to Digital, Then Convert to a 1 to 8 level LED display

Tags: digital-logic, analog

Getting back into electronics as a hobby, and I'm giving myself some breadboard tasks and drills to do to refamiliarize myself with both simple analog and digital circuitry.

Here's what I want to do: 5VDC source, with a pot (say, 100k). I want to take that analog signal and drive 8 leds which light up between 1 and 8 of them at a time depending on the relative output of the analog signal.

My first thought is 8 bit analog to digital. Got ahold of the ADC0804 chip (https://circuits-diy.com/adc0804lcn-8-bit-a-d-converter-datasheet/)

Simple hookup with a pot driving the V+ relative input, and my output was hooked to 8 leds through some current limiting resistors. I turn the POT and the output is 8 bit binary value displayed on the 8 leds.

Success!

But now my thought is, rather than displaying an 8 bit binary value, let's drive 8 leds which turn on successively more lights as the 8 bit output goes up. At first glance it might SEEMS like the same thing, but it's not.

For example, let's say the 8 bit output is 0b10000000. When displaying binary, of course, bit 7 is on, and bits 0-6 are off.

But I don't want to do that. That value is 128, which is half of 255, so the lowest 4 lights out of 8 should be on instead.

I'm racking my brain as to how to convert this without a simple microprocessor, which I can easily do. Probably could do it with TON of logic gates, but is there a 1 or 2 chip solution for this? I'm going through a bunch of data sheets, but since I don't know what this might be called it's difficult to find a prepackaged solution. Maybe I didn't need to convert to 8 bit digital in the first place, and there's a simple driver to accomplish this already?

This truth table might help (I've added some logic tables below the truth table). The logic table is how I could accomplish this with AND and OR gates. Would still love to know if there's a chip designed for something like this.

[image]

Comment: Decode the three high bits to seven of the LEDs and the last LED to the fourth most significant bit?

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome sounds like a winner, make that an answer.

Comment: decode it using what? Understood the high 3 bits essentially count from 0 to 7, how do I convert that to 8 separate leds? This pointed me closer to the right direction. the 74238 gets me CLOSE, as it will light up between 0 and 7 lines, but only 1 at a time...

Comment: I had written an answer only to realize I that decodes logarithmically.  Rather than that maybe using a 74xx series bar driver, I'll write that up instead.

Comment: I'm being dumb (long day, I was linear to begin with...)

Comment: What you're trying to do is called thermometer encoding. Every Flash ADC inherently converts an analog input into thermometer code. Unfortunately, they also encode it back to plain old binary code internally, so there's no way to tap that

Comment: You could try and build your own Flash ADC out of discrete components. Linearity is not guaranteed, thought, and you'll need a lot of resistors and a bunch of op-amps

Comment: Victor, thanks for the info on what that's called (makes sense). I may do what you're suggesting as an exercise for myself.

Comment: I will be building out of some discrete components and will report back!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to (I assume linearly) may the 8 bit level to having one of the 8 LEDs on I would suggest the following mapping: decode the 3 highest bits to one each of 7 of the LEDs and then map the fourth most significant bit to the 8<sup>th</sup> LED.  You won't need to ever consider the lowest 4 bits.  See the truth table below.

| ADC Bits | LEDs |
| --- | --- |
| 111xxxxx | 10000000 |
| 110xxxxx | 01000000 |
| 101xxxxx | 00100000 |
| 100xxxxx | 00010000 |
| 011xxxxx | 00001000 |
| 010xxxxx | 00000100 |
| 001xxxxx | 00000010 |
| 0001xxxx | 00000001 |
| 0000xxxx | 00000000 |

You can decode the top 3 bits with a 3 to 8 decoder IC like the [74LS138](https://components101.com/ics/74ls138-3-8-line-decoder-ic) anding the lowest order output with the 4th most significant bit for the final output.

Comment: Close, see my edit above with the truth table. I also want to turn on all leds "below" the top most lit up.

Comment: And if you have something logarithmic like sound, take the leftmost 1 in your value and set that light and all the others beneath  it.

Comment: @LarryBud I see, if someone doesn't write up a more complete answer before me I'll update tomorrow (or sooner) when I get a chance.

Comment: Appreciate it! I will continue to look to see if something is premade for this or if I have to get a little more basic with logic gates.